# Combo box string as input for a button

Tags: arcpy, python-addin

I built a python addin for Arcmap and I need to print a folder path to a combo box, which should be a destination folder to copy my *.gdb file.

[image]

After a click on a "Backup" button this tool should copy my file to a folder on the right. But still I don't know how to figure that out. The only thing I can see is to read the last thing in Arcmap's python window and probably set it as input for a button.

[image]

But still have no idea even how to perform it.

**EDIT:**

I was changing only lines in python script, config.xml was made by default.
Here is a piece of code:

```
import arcpy
import pythonaddins

class Backup(object):
    """Implementation for BackupServer_addin.Backup (Button)"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.enabled = True
        self.checked = False
    def onClick(self):
        if "" in BackupServer_addin.Folder.self.items:
            print self.items

class Folder(object):
    """Implementation for BackupServer_addin.Folder (ComboBox)"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = [""]
        self.editable = True
        self.enabled = True
        self.dropdownWidth = 'WWWWWW'
        self.width = 'WWWWWW'
    def onSelChange(self, selection):
        print "New Selection:",selection
    def onEditChange(self, text):
        print "Edit Change:",text
    def onFocus(self, focused):
        pass
    def onEnter(self):
        print "Current Value:",self.value
    def refresh(self):
        pass
```

This string is just a try to make a reference to the Folder combobox  `if "" in BackupServer_addin.Folder.self.items:`

Here are the contents of config.xml:

```
<ESRI.Configuration xmlns="http://schemas.esri.com/Desktop/AddIns" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><Name>Python Addin</Name><AddInID>{413e6443-7e28-43e0-832a-33730a790ca4}</AddInID><Description>New Addin</Description><Version>0.1</Version><Image /><Author>Untitled</Author><Company>Untitled</Company><Date>02/03/2017</Date><Targets><Target name="Desktop" version="10.2" /></Targets><AddIn language="PYTHON" library="BackupServer_addin.py" namespace="BackupServer_addin"><ArcMap>
    <Commands>
        <Button caption="Backup" category="Python Addin" class="Backup" id="BackupServer_addin.Backup" image="Images\backup.png" message="Backup" tip="Backup"><Help heading="Backup">Backup</Help></Button>
        <ComboBox caption="Folder" category="Python Addin" class="Folder" id="BackupServer_addin.Folder" itemSizeString="WWWWWW" message="Folder" rows="4" sizeString="WWWWWW" tip="Folder"><Help heading="Folder">Folder</Help></ComboBox>
        </Commands>
    <Extensions>
        </Extensions>
    <Toolbars>
        <Toolbar caption="Toolbar" category="Python Addin" id="BackupServer_addin.toolbar" showInitially="true"><Items><Button refID="BackupServer_addin.Backup" /><ComboBox refID="BackupServer_addin.Folder" /></Items></Toolbar>
        </Toolbars>
    <Menus>
        </Menus>
    </ArcMap></AddIn></ESRI.Configuration>
```

Comment: What does your code to do what you describe look like?  i.e. both the config.xml and your Python script.

Comment: @PolyGeo updated the question

Comment: Can you include the config.xml too, please?

Comment: @PolyGeo updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found a solution: making of **global** parameter and putting it firstly into combo box parameters and then to button's:

**Combobox:**

```
class FolderPath(object):
    """Implementation for BackupPlus_addin.FolderPath (ComboBox)"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = [""]
        self.editable = True
        self.enabled = True
        self.dropdownWidth = 'WWWWWW'
        self.width = 'WWWWWW'
    def onSelChange(self, selection):
        print "New Selection:",selection
    def onEditChange(self, text):
        print "Edit Change:",text
        global fc
        fc = text
    def onFocus(self, focused):
        pass
    def onEnter(self):
        print "Current Value:",self.value
    def refresh(self):
        pass
```

**Button:**

```
class BackupToFolder(object):
    """Implementation for BackupPlus_addin.BackupToFolder (Button)"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.enabled = True
        self.checked = False
    def onClick(self):
        import arcpy
        import os
        import time

        from arcpy import env
        mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
        df = mxd.activeDataFrame
        arcpy.env.overwriteOutput=True
        global fc 
        #some code
```